# How to get most recent and second recent values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have table containing data related to Risks and I have to get most recent and 2nd second recent data from Risk Table

Data in table is as follow:

```
RiskID        RiskName     RiskScore       RiskDate    ItemID      
1             ABC            10          23/10/2013       12            
1             ABC            8           20/12/2013       12 
1             ABC            5           15/01/2014       12
2             BC             9           19/09/2013       12
2             BC             10          17/12/2013       12
2             BC             9           12/01/2014       12
```

Where I am looking for result like below where ItemID should be 12

```
R_ID   R_Name  Recent_R_Date  Recent_R_Score  Second_R_Date   Second_R_Date  ItemID
1       ABC       15/01/2014      5              20/12/2013       8           12
2       BC        12/01/2014      9             17/12/2013        10          12
```

Comment: I have no SQL Server here to test. I think you should use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RISKID ORDER BY RISKDATE DESC) AS V`. Then you choose only `V` less or equal than 2. Finally you pivot your table by `V` and `JOIN` this result with the table itself. It will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it (which also works in SQL Server 2008)

```
SELECT RiskID, RiskName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN RiskDate END) RecentDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN RiskScore END) RecentScore,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN RiskDate END) SecondDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN RiskScore END) SecondScore,
       ItemID
  FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RiskID ORDER BY RiskDate DESC) rnum
    FROM Risk
   WHERE ItemID = 12
) q
 WHERE rnum <= 2
 GROUP BY ItemID, RiskID, RiskName
 ORDER BY RiskID
```

Output:

```
| RISKID | RISKNAME | RECENTDATE | RECENTSCORE | SECONDDATE | SECONDSCORE | ITEMID |
|--------|----------|------------|-------------|------------|-------------|--------|
|      1 |      ABC | 2014-01-15 |           5 | 2013-12-20 |           8 |     12 |
|      2 |       BC | 2014-01-12 |           9 | 2013-12-17 |          10 |     12 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb13c/2)** demo

Comment: Thank you Stuart and Peterm for your prompt replies. Let me try these

Comment: Works well, just like i suggested in my comments. Great!

Comment: @StuartLC  although I am using SQL Server 2012, but when I am executing query I got this " error 'LAG' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: @peterm and I also have to add a condition like WHERE ItemID = 38 So that I'll get risks related to ItemID =12

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

Since you've tagged with `sql-server-2012`, you will have access to the LEAD and [LAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) analytic functions, which allow you to 'peek' at other rows. I've also assumed you need to 'partition by' the `RiskName`.

```
SELECT TOP 2
    RiskId, RiskName, RiskDate AS Recent_R_Date, RiskScore AS Recent_R_Score, 
    LAG(RiskDate) OVER (PARTITION BY RiskName ORDER BY RiskDate ASC) AS Second_R_Date,
    LAG(RiskScore) OVER (PARTITION BY RiskName ORDER BY RiskDate ASC) AS Second_R_Score,
    ItemID
 FROM Risk
 WHERE ItemID = 12
 ORDER BY RiskDate DESC;
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f601/11)

<del>It should be as simple as ordering by date DESC and then limiting the result to 2, viz:

    SELECT TOP 2 
        R_ID, R_Name, Recent_R_Date, Recent_R_Score, 
        Second_R_Date, Second_R_Date, ItemID
     FROM Risks
     WHERE ItemID = 12
     ORDER BY RiskDate DESC;</del>

Comment: The TOP 2 is not necessary anymore, is it? I mean in the case of having more than 2 different RISKID records.

Comment: OP's example output shows just 2 rows returned, so wanted to be consistent. But yes, it has no bearing on the LAG.

Comment: @Nizam It is now that I've partitioned by RiskName - I didn't pick that up / OP didn't mention it, although was implied in the required output table.